# Why is the strong_parameters method private?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, security, ruby-on-rails-4, strong-parameters

The rails scaffolds give you the resource_params method as private by default:

```ruby
private

def person_params
  params.require(:person).permit(:name, :age)
end
```

I understand why strong_parameters is a good thing.  I also understand that this prevents the method from being accessed outside the controller, but are there any real dangers to making this method public, or what is the reasoning behind having this as a private method? It would be nice to be able to send that method to the controller from a gem that extends ActionController.

In other words, why *not* access the method outside of the controller?  For example, if I have a separate controller that handles authorization and I want to pass an instance variable back to the original controller that contains the initialized object.

Comment: Because there is no advantage to expose them outside world.. It is not for them.. It is for application security..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because this method is not called from any external objects.
Mass assignment protection is not connected with 'person params' method visibility, it is just best practice for application design

Controllers using to handless only one request by app design. You should not call methods from one controller in another. If you want to share methods for several controllers, you can use inheritance, mixins, or service objects

inheritance

```
class BaseController < ApplicationController
  private
  def shared_method
  end
end

class UsersController < BaseController
   def index
     shared_method
   end
end
```

mixin

```
module SomeMixin
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern 
  included do
    def shared_method
    end
  end
end

class UsersController < ApplicationController
  include SomeMixin
   def index
     shared_method
   end
end
```

service object

```
class SomeService
   def shared_method(params)
     # process params
   end
end

class UsersController < ApplicationController
  include SomeMixin
   def index
     SomeService.new.shared_method(params)
   end
end
```

Comment: "Mass assignment protection is not connected with 'person params' method visibility, it is just best practice for application design" - that's what I was sort of expecting.. thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It wasn't always this way and it's there to protect you.  Check out this great [blog post](http://www.sitepoint.com/rails-4-quick-look-strong-parameters/) on the subject.

Here are some relevant snippets:

> Problem with Mass-Assignment: Security vulnerability
>
> Mass-assignment saves us the need to assign values to each attribute
>   of the model, but it can create problems. Since we aren’t restricting
>   which attributes can be set nor are we checking the valus of these
>   attributes, a malicious hacker could assign any value to any
>   attribute. In our example, he could set the value of admin true,
>   making himself a super user.
>
> Here is what the url might look like
>
> [http://www.example.com/user/signup?user[name]=ow3ned&user[admin]=1](http://www.example.com/user/signup?user%5bname%5d=ow3ned&user%5badmin%5d=1)

Users are able to exploit this if they know even a little bit about your models and cause issues.

Answer (score 0):

In most languages there are classifications in a class for methods, attributes or whatever else it may contain.

Depending on language or inheritence, default behaviour might be public, private...

In ruby, classes by default contain public methods and attributes. You need to specify if a method is private.

The public method or attribute:
This is accessible from out of the class or the instance of the class. So, if you have class:

```
class Foo
    def my_id
         10
    end

    private
        def my_class
             "Bar"
        end

    public
        def my_friend
             "Zonk"
        end
end
```

Then:

```
2.0.0p247 :001 > @foo = Foo.new

2.0.0p247 :002 > @foo.my_id
 => 10

2.0.0p247 :003 > @foo.my_class
NoMethodError: undefined method `my_class' for #<Foo:0x000000045a53f8>

2.0.0p247 :004 > @foo.my_friend
 => "Zonk"
```

You see than you can change from private to public as you wish, though maybe not a very good idea.